# Reading/Writing a Map<String, Object> from/to DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pojo, dynamodb-queries

I have a use case where I want to read a Map from DynamoDB in Java. The problem I am facing is how do I convert the Map into a POJO in Java. For example, let the following be the content in Dynamo DB

```
{
    "someInfo": {
         "age" : {
            minAge : xx,
            maxAge : yy,
          },
         "city" : "abc",
         "education" : {
             "university" : "xyz",
             "major" : "def"
          }
     }
}
```

In my Java service, I want to read this into an object, say as Map. City, Education, Age are all Java classes of their own. How to model this data as a class? Will the following model work:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "someotherinfo")
@Getter @Setter
public class SomeOtherInfo {


    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    private Long id;

    private Map<String, Object> someInfo;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I was thinking maybe, I could have someInfo as Map and will serialize and deserialize the objects into JSON when writing and reading from the table. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own `SomeInfo` class:

```
class SomeInfo{
    private City city;
    private Age age;
    private Education education;

    // constructors

    // getters and setters
}
```

And then reference that instead of the map:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "someotherinfo")
@Getter @Setter
public class SomeOtherInfo {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    private Long id;

    private SomeInfo someInfo;
}
```

Comment: SomeInfo will not always have Age, City and Education fields. Say fro Id 1, SomeInfo has only Age and for Id 2, SomeInfo will only have education. Will this situation be able to handle this and what if I have another property, say MusicPreference that I have to add to SomeInfo class. Will I be able to add it without breaking existing data read/update